# Cannot download certain apps after Windows 10 upgrade

Tags: windows-10-mobile, apps, store

I have a Lumia 1020. Originally it was on Windows Phone 8.1 and I did the Insider Preview to get a preview of Windows 10 Mobile. During that time, I downloaded some apps/games and they worked fine. Some time later, I did a hard reset back to WP8. Then I was able to upgrade it to the most recent version of W10 (not Insider Preview).

Now I can't redownload a couple apps/games from the Windows Store. They are still in My Library, but clicking on them leads me to the "Something happened on our end. Waiting a bit might help" page.

The specific one I really want is "Civilization II". Note, that is not the true Civ 2 or Civ Revolution, but rather a port of Civ 1.

Comment: I can't see that specific app in the store - do you have a link?

Comment: Apps, even Microsoft-made ones but definitely third-party ones, sometimes get pulled from the store. When this happens, they don't get deleted from your device automatically but you can't (re)install them any more. It really sucks when this happens to popular/useful apps, but that's the joy of a closed ecosystem. The only way around it that I know of is to get the .XAP/.APPX from somebody who already has it and install that on your phone, and most people won't be able to help with that.

Comment: When I wrote the question it was there, but I just checked again now and it's gone! The picture was the box art for Civilization II: [link](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/7/73/Civ2boxart.jpg) @CBHacking they probably yanked it due to it being an unsanctioned port. You should should post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was pulled.

After looking at @CBHacking's comment, it appears that the app was pulled from the store. When I posted the question, it was in My Library but inaccessible. Then it was completely removed from My Library a short time later. So Microsoft was probably in the process of removing it and now it is totally gone.

Answer (score 1):

Yup this happens on the compatibility basis. It can happen in both the ways for example [icircuit](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/icircuit/9wzdncrdc280) is an app that will install on Windows 10 mobile devices but not on the Windows Phone 8 devices. Here is the link. you can't get the store page on a device running Windows 8.1. Alright. And here is another example of this. Live lock screen beta. A Microsoft app. It's not available for Windows 10 mobile devices. here is the [link](https://www.appx4fun.com/xap/3454/) but you can't get it on a device running Windows 10 mobile. And you will face down the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Some apps that are no more available in the Microsoft Store for 8.1 could however be retrieved using the "Sysapp Pusher" app.

2 examples as of today Feb 14, 2017 : "Lumia Panorama" and "Call + sms filter".

Besides the problem discussed here, I noted also that some apps are still there ... but do not operate properly anymore.  Example : "Foto Slideshow".

On the other hand, some useful apps have been added as "B2X-smartapp" ( excellent ! ), "Hardware tests", "Firmware update check".

( tested on 620 / 630 / 640 )